# How to check if UNIXTimeStamp is mid day time or evening in php

Tags: php, json, unix-timestamp

I have the JSON Response which contains DateTime in UNIXTIMESTAMP. I would like find that the time in JSON Response is of Mid Day time or evening.

Lets say below is the response and I want to check CloseTime weather it is mid day time or evening time.

```
{
    "gameName": "NUMBERS", 
    "id": "16440", 
    "status": "RESULTS_AVAILABLE", 
    "closeTime": "1491927615000"
}
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/DIXZS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you..decode your json and  assign closeTime to $timestamp

```
 <?php
    $timestamp = 1491927615000;
    $date = date('H', $timestamp);

    if($date < 12){

         echo "good morning";

       }elseif($date > 11 && $date < 18){

         echo "good afternoon";

       }elseif($date > 17){

         echo "good evening";

       }


    ?>
```

http://codepad.org/SCJw32FL